# slider changes on mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am using bootstrap carousel slider on my website. I want slides to change on mouseScroll.how can I do this.this code works fine but I want to change slides on mouseScroll
 this is my  code

```
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#product_slider").owlCarousel({  
         rtl:true,
         loop:true,                                                           
         margin:4,
         autoplay:false,
         autoplayTimeout:10000,
         autoplayHoverPause:true,
         lazyLoad : true,
         pagination:false,
         nav:true,
          dots: false,
         navText:false ,
         responsive:{
         0:{
             items:1
         },
         500:{
             items:1
         },
         768:{
             items:4
         },
         1200:{
             items:5

         }
        }
      });

     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make the carousel change when you scroll the mouse wheel over it. I think it would be wise to prevent the whole page from scrolling while your mouse is over the carousel, but I haven't taken the time to do that here.
Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mikeferrari/z34m1wbo/

```
// select the carousel container
var myelement = document.getElementById("myCarousel"); 

// this function is called every time the mouse wheel is scrolled
function makeItSo() {
  // this is where you tell it to go to the next slide
  $('.carousel').carousel('next')
}

myelement.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {      
    makeItSo();
});


// start your carousel on page load
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
```

Comment: but it shows an error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function"

Comment: Have you changed it to match your code? You need to substitute myCarousel in the example code with your selector .owlCarousel